# Sort list in .asp page using vbscript

Tags: forms, sorting, asp-classic, vbscript, radio-button

I have added three radio buttons and I want these buttons to sort the list of data that is displayed on an asp classic page. The data is pulled off a database and the code below is what I have got so far to get this sorting done but I haven't been able to complete it. First of all I would like to get an onSelect submit option which will refresh the page or list(refreshing the list would be better) and have the list sorted accordingly as to what order was selected by the user.

***The code for the radio buttons***

```
<form method=get action=featuredvehicle.asp>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="make">Make<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="model">Model<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="model_year">Model Year
</form>
```

***The code for getting the value from the radio button***

```
<%
Dim strSQL1
Dim OrderList
OrderList = Request.QueryString("sort")
If OrderList = "" Then
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM featuredvehicles ORDER by make, model, model_year asc;"
ElseIf OrderList = make THEN
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM featuredvehicles ORDER by make, model, model_year asc;"
ElseIf OrderList = model THEN
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM featuredvehicles ORDER by model, model, model_year asc;"
rsLogbook.Open strSQL1, adoCon
ElseIf OrderList = model_year THEN
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM featuredvehicles ORDER by model_year, make, model asc;"
END IF
rsLogbook.Open strSQL1, adoCon
%>
```

***The code for listing the list from the database.***

```
<blockquote>

<% rsLogbook.Movefirst
do while not rsLogbook.EOF %>  
    <p align="left" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="#5A87B4">
    <img border="0" src="images/obdkey_icon.gif"><a href="http://websitelink.com?vehicle=<%Response.Write(rsLogbook("id"))%>">
    <%=rsLogbook("make")%>&nbsp;<%=rsLogbook("model")%>&nbsp;<%=rsLogbook("model_year")%></a>
       <%Response.Write("<br />") %>
<% rsLogbook.MoveNext%></font></p>
<%loop %>  
</blockquote>
```

Once again what I would like to do is to

1. Have an on select submit option for the radio button
2. Grab the value selected from the radio buttons and sort the list
   accordingly (by refreshing list or any other way necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to make the query and listing a single code block. Concatenate your output substrings and the record fields and then write the whole line with a single `response.write` instruction.

```
<blockquote>
<%
Dim strSQL1
Dim OrderList
OrderList = Request.QueryString("sort")
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM featuredvehicles ORDER BY "
Select Case OrderList
  Case "", make   : strSQL1 = strSQL1 & "make, model, model_year ASC;"
  Case model      : strSQL1 = strSQL1 & "model, make, model_year ASC;"
  Case model_year : strSQL1 = strSQL1 & "model_year, make, model ASC;"
End Select
rsLogbook.Open strSQL1, adoCon

rsLogbook.Movefirst
do while not rsLogbook.EOF
  response.write "<p align=""left"" style=""margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0""><font face=""Tahoma"" size=""2"" color=""#5A87B42"">" _
    & "<img border=""0"" src=""images/obdkey_icon.gif""><a href=""http://websitelink.com?vehicle=" & rsLogbook("id") & """>" _
    & rsLogbook("make") & "&nbsp;" & rsLogbook("model") & "&nbsp;" & rsLogbook("model_year") & "</a><br /></font></p>"
  rsLogbook.MoveNext</font></p>
loop
%>
</blockquote>
```

That said, if your data doesn't change very frequently and you just want your users to be able to change the order of the result set on the fly, you should not run repeated queries against the database (with different `ORDER BY` clauses). That would put undue load on both the web server and the database.

In this scenario it would be better to retrieve the result set just once (either unordered or with a default order) and do any subsequent (re-)ordering of the results with some client-side JavaScript framework (e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).